# 'Tab' button deletes code instead of push code forward

Tags: android-studio, tabs, editor

I'm using android studio version 3.2.1 'October 9' and in both Java and XML editor, the `Tab` button (when multiple lines selected) deletes selected code with 3 space characters instead of pushing selected code forward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Preferences > Keymap then search for "indent selection", it should be bind on tab

[image: Preferences]
Or you can click on Editor menu, then "Indent Selection"